# How can I add a 2nd picture on my cover page and have it slightly overlap the first?

Tags: macros, graphics, function

I have been using and adapting my university's Latex template for a year now. I mostly manage by snooping around the code and reading the commented code. So far I've managed to adapt some shapes, change the colours and also the cover images and logos.

Today I wanted to add a 2nd cover image but I'm not understanding the function definitions that are happening in the setup file.

[image: Example of what I want]

Here is the lines of code that define this cover page presently:

```
% Cover page %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\def \UEm {\@matiere}
\def \UEc {\@UEcourt}

\makeatletter
\def\@titre{titre}
\newcommand{\titre}[1]{\def\@titre{#1}}

\def\@soustitre{soustitre}
\newcommand{\soustitre}[1]{\def\@soustitre{#1}}

\def\@pgimage{pgimage}
\newcommand{\pgimage}[1]{\def\@pgimage{#1}}

\def\@etudiants{etudiants}
\newcommand{\etudiants}[1]{\def\@etudiants{#1}}

\def\@noms{noms}
\newcommand{\noms}[1]{\def\@noms{#1}}

\def\@matiere{matiere}
\newcommand{\matiere}[1]{\def\@matiere{#1}}

\def\@UEcourt{UEcourt}
\newcommand{\UEcourt}[1]{\def\@UEcourt{#1}}

\makeatother

% Geometry of the cover page %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\newcommand\BackgroundPic{ %
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
        \begin{scope}[shift={(current page.west)}]
            \draw[draw=Jaune-UPS,fill=Jaune-UPS] (0,-50) rectangle (25,50);
            \draw[draw=Gris-UPS,fill=Gris-UPS] (0.75,-14.25) rectangle (25,-50);
            \draw[draw=Gris-UPS,fill=Gris-UPS] (0.5,-12.75) rectangle (1.5,-12.25);
            \draw[draw=Gris-UPS,fill=Gris-UPS] (0.5,-13) rectangle (1.5,-13.5);
            \draw[draw=Gris-UPS,fill=Gris-UPS] (0.5,-13.75) rectangle (1.5,-15);
            \node[rotate=90,anchor=west] at(0.75,-12){\textcolor{darkgray}{\textbf{\textsc{\UEm}}}};
            \node[rotate=90,anchor=west] at(1.25,-12){\textcolor{darkgray}{\textsc{\UEc}}};
            \draw[draw=Gris-UPS,fill=Gris-UPS] (0.5,-1.35) rectangle (1.5,-1.1);
            \draw[draw=Gris-UPS,fill=Gris-UPS] (0.5,-0.9) rectangle (1.5,-0.4);
            \draw[draw=Gris-UPS,fill=Gris-UPS] (0.5,-0.2) rectangle (1.5,0.8);
            \draw[draw=Gris-UPS,fill=Gris-UPS] (0.5,1) rectangle (1.5,50);
            %
            \node[inner sep=0pt,anchor=north east] at (20.5,14.5) {\includegraphics[width=.5\textwidth]{Template/JJ.png}};
        \end{scope}
    \end{tikzpicture}}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\pagedegarde}{
\newgeometry{top=2.5cm, bottom=1cm, left=2cm, right=1cm}
\AddToShipoutPicture*{\BackgroundPic}
  \begin{titlepage}
  \centering
    \vspace*{4cm}
        {\huge\bfseries\color{Gris-UPS} \@titre}\\
    \vspace*{3mm}
        {\LARGE\color{Gris-UPS}\@soustitre}\\
    \vspace{1cm}
        {\Large {\bfseries\color{Gris-UPS} \@etudiants}}\\
    \vfill
        \hspace*{5.15cm}\includegraphics[height=.75\textwidth]{\@pgimage} %IMAGE DE COUVERTURE
    \vfill
        {\color{Gris-UPS} \@date} \\
  \end{titlepage}
\restoregeometry
}
\makeatother
```

So far I've tried making a new "function":

```
\def\@pgimage2{pgimage2}
\newcommand{\pgimage2}[1]{\def\@pgimage2{#1}}
```

But the code doesn't highlight (the colour of it) properly so I feel like I'm doing something wrong.

Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance!

PS: I forgot to add a working example so I will do so now.
My Overleaf document has 2 main files and then the content is added via .tex files. The first main file is CRinfo.sty and the 2nd is main.tex

Here are the contents of CRinfo.sty, I have translated the important comments and sections.

```
%  CRinfo.sty   Cédric Roosz, 16/11/2022
%
%  Style dédié aux comptes rendus d'Informatique Scientifique 3
%  Université Toulouse III Paul Sabatier

% Packages for FR %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fourier} % Bibliothèque de caractères
\usepackage{natbib} % Format de bibliographie
\usepackage{babel}

% Packages for writing, format, symbols, etc. %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\usepackage{fourier,amssymb,amsfonts,amsmath,latexsym,fontawesome,setspace,enumitem} % Librairies diverses (police, symboles, listes)
\usepackage{dirtytalk}
\usepackage{lipsum,ulem,hyperref} % Librairies diverses (lipsum, soulignage, liens URL)
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true,linkcolor=blue,filecolor=magenta,urlcolor=cyan}
\usepackage[a4paper, margin=2.5cm]{geometry} % Format des marges
\usepackage{fancyhdr,eso-pic} % Format des entêtes, pieds de pages, fonds
\setlength{\headheight}{15pt} % Taille de l'entête
\fancyhead[L]{\scshape\@noms} % Paramètre de l'entête gauche
\fancyhead[R]{\leftmark} % Paramètre de l'entête droite
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{1pt} % Ligne sous l'entête
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{1pt} % Ligne sur le pied de page
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage} % Numéro de page
\pagestyle{fancy}
\usepackage{booktabs,tabularx,array,graphicx, tabularray, multirow} % Format des tableaux, figures
\usepackage{tikz} % Outils de dessins
\setlength{\parindent}{1cm} % Pas d'indentation en début de paragraphe
\setlist[itemize]{label=$\bullet$} % Symbole pour les listes

% Parameters to insert code %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\usepackage{minted} % Permet d'afficher des bouts de codes
\usemintedstyle[python]{default}  % Thème d'affichage python
\usemintedstyle[latex]{default}  % Thème d'affichage latex
\setminted[python]{frame=lines,framesep=2mm,baselinestretch=1.2,bgcolor=GrisClair,fontsize=\footnotesize,linenos}
\setminted[latex]{frame=lines,framesep=2mm,baselinestretch=1.2,fontsize=\footnotesize}
\renewcommand{\listingscaption}{Extrait de code} % Légende code
\renewcommand{\listoflistingscaption}{Liste des extraits de codes} %Titre liste de codes
\newminted{python}{frame=lines,framesep=2mm,baselinestretch=1.2,bgcolor=GrisClair,fontsize=\footnotesize,linenos}

% University colours %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{Orange-UPS}{RGB}{243,150,47}
\definecolor{Jaune-UPS}{RGB}{243,150,47}
\definecolor{Gris-UPS}{RGB}{53,53,53}
\definecolor{GrisClair}{RGB}{240,240,240}
\definecolor{BlancCasse}{RGB}{244,237,222}

% Cover page format %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\def \UEm {\@matiere}
\def \UEc {\@UEcourt}

\makeatletter
\def\@titre{titre}
\newcommand{\titre}[1]{\def\@titre{#1}}

\def\@soustitre{soustitre}
\newcommand{\soustitre}[1]{\def\@soustitre{#1}}

\def\@pgimage{pgimage}
\newcommand{\pgimage}[1]{\def\@pgimage{#1}}

\def\@etudiants{etudiants}
\newcommand{\etudiants}[1]{\def\@etudiants{#1}}

\def\@noms{noms}
\newcommand{\noms}[1]{\def\@noms{#1}}

\def\@matiere{matiere}
\newcommand{\matiere}[1]{\def\@matiere{#1}}

\def\@UEcourt{UEcourt}
\newcommand{\UEcourt}[1]{\def\@UEcourt{#1}}

\makeatother

% Cover Page Geometry       %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\newcommand\BackgroundPic{ %
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
        \begin{scope}[shift={(current page.west)}]
            \draw[draw=Jaune-UPS,fill=Jaune-UPS] (0,-50) rectangle (25,50);
            \draw[draw=Gris-UPS,fill=Gris-UPS] (0.75,-14.25) rectangle (25,-50);
            \draw[draw=Gris-UPS,fill=Gris-UPS] (0.5,-12.75) rectangle (1.5,-12.25);
            \draw[draw=Gris-UPS,fill=Gris-UPS] (0.5,-13) rectangle (1.5,-13.5);
            \draw[draw=Gris-UPS,fill=Gris-UPS] (0.5,-13.75) rectangle (1.5,-15);
            \node[rotate=90,anchor=west] at(0.75,-12){\textcolor{darkgray}{\textbf{\textsc{\UEm}}}};
            \node[rotate=90,anchor=west] at(1.25,-12){\textcolor{darkgray}{\textsc{\UEc}}};
            \draw[draw=Gris-UPS,fill=Gris-UPS] (0.5,-1.35) rectangle (1.5,-1.1);
            \draw[draw=Gris-UPS,fill=Gris-UPS] (0.5,-0.9) rectangle (1.5,-0.4);
            \draw[draw=Gris-UPS,fill=Gris-UPS] (0.5,-0.2) rectangle (1.5,0.8);
            \draw[draw=Gris-UPS,fill=Gris-UPS] (0.5,1) rectangle (1.5,50);
            %
            \node[inner sep=0pt,anchor=north east] at (20.5,14.5) {\includegraphics[width=.5\textwidth]{Template/JJ.png}};
        \end{scope}
    \end{tikzpicture}}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\pagedegarde}{
\newgeometry{top=2.5cm, bottom=1cm, left=2cm, right=1cm}
\AddToShipoutPicture*{\BackgroundPic}
  \begin{titlepage}
  \centering
    \vspace*{4cm}
        {\huge\bfseries\color{Gris-UPS} \@titre}\\
    \vspace*{3mm}
        {\LARGE\color{Gris-UPS}\@soustitre}\\
    \vspace{1cm}
        {\Large {\bfseries\color{Gris-UPS} \@etudiants}}\\
    \vfill
        \hspace*{5.15cm}\includegraphics[height=.85\textwidth]{\@pgimage} %IMAGE DE COUVERTURE
    \vfill
        {\color{Gris-UPS} \@date} \\
  \end{titlepage}
\restoregeometry
}
\makeatother

% Specific Commands %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


% Changing margins
\def\changemargin#1#2{\list{}{\rightmargin#2\leftmargin#1}\item[]}
\let\endchangemargin=\endlist


% Geometry of the transition page %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\newcommand\TransitionPic{ %
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
        \begin{scope}[shift={(current page.west)}]
            \draw[draw=Jaune-UPS,fill=Jaune-UPS] (0,-50) rectangle (25,50);
            % \draw[draw=Gris-UPS,fill=Gris-UPS] (0,50) rectangle (20.5,14.25);
            % \draw[draw=Gris-UPS,fill=Gris-UPS] (0,-14.25) rectangle (20.5,-50);

            
            \draw[draw=Gris-UPS,fill=Gris-UPS] (19.5,-12.75) rectangle (20.5,-12.25);
            \draw[draw=Gris-UPS,fill=Gris-UPS] (19.5,-13) rectangle (20.5,-13.5);
            \draw[draw=Gris-UPS,fill=Gris-UPS] (19.5,-13.75) rectangle (20.5,-15);
            \node[rotate=270,anchor=west] at(20.25,-1.5){\textcolor{darkgray}{\textbf{\textsc{\UEm}}}};
            \node[rotate=270,anchor=west] at(19.75,-1.5){\textcolor{darkgray}{\textsc{\UEc}}};
            \draw[draw=Gris-UPS,fill=Gris-UPS] (19.5,-1.35) rectangle (20.5,-1.1);
            \draw[draw=Gris-UPS,fill=Gris-UPS] (19.5,-0.9) rectangle (20.5,-0.4);
            \draw[draw=Gris-UPS,fill=Gris-UPS] (19.5,-0.2) rectangle (20.5,0.8);
            
            % \draw[draw=Gris-UPS,fill=Gris-UPS] (0.5,1) rectangle (1.5,50);
            \draw[draw=Gris-UPS,fill=Gris-UPS] (19.5,1) rectangle (20.5,50);

            \draw[draw=Gris-UPS,fill=Gris-UPS] (0,-50) rectangle (0.125,50);
           
        \end{scope}
    \end{tikzpicture}}
```

Then here is main.tex, also translated the necessary comments:

```
\documentclass[english,12pt,a4paper]{article} %Définition du type de document
\usepackage{CRinfo} %Import du fichier de style (format du document)

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Title, authors, date, etc. %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\titre{Diagnostic \say{Les Mûriers}} %Insérez ici le titre de votre document
\vspace{1cm}
\soustitre{ATELIER DIAGNOSTIC}
\etudiants{Gauthier DUPONT, Nicolas EVENO, Eugénie SALIGNAT, Camille VIDAL} %Insérez ici vos noms et prénoms
\noms{Dupont, Eveno, Salignat, Vidal}
\date{14 Février 2024} 
\pgimage{Couverture1.jpg} %cover page image
\matiere{Master Urbanisme et Aménagement}
\UEcourt{Parcours Villes, Habitat et Transition Écologique}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Document Start    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}

\pagedegarde % insertion of the cover page

\newpage
\tableofcontents % Table des matières
\newpage

%\listoffigures
%\listoftables
%\listoflistings

%\input{Contenu/P0_Introduction}
\input{Contenu/P1}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Sorry, but I doubt that anybody can reproduce your problem with the shown code snippet. To increase your chances of a qualified answer, you should always show a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/277964) that makes the problem reproducible without further changes. Such an example usually starts with `\documentclass`, contains only the required preamble code and the required packages and additionally a `\begin{document}...\end{document}` part.

Comment: However, it seems, you are already using package [`eso-pic`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/eso-pic). This package allows to print whatever you want at the background or foreground either of every page or the next page. Please, see the manual of the package for more information.

Comment: @cabohah 
I've added the necessary code to reproduce the example.
Thanks for pointing me towards the eso-pic documentation!

Comment: It still does not compile without error, e.g., it still needs external files, e.g., `Couverture1.jpg`, `Template/JJ.png`, `Contenu/P1.tex`. And you are loading packages, that are irrelevant for the problem and makes it harder to analyze your code. However, as already told, you can e.g. add `\AddToShipoutPictureFG*{\AtTextLowerLeft{\includegraphics[width=10cm]{example-image}}}` before `\pagedegarde` (or somewhere at the definition of this command) to add an additional picture on the cover page overlapping the existing one. See the `eso-pic` manual for more information.

Comment: Alternatively you also can change the definition of `\BackgroundPic` to add one more node with one more `\includegraphics` command similar to the already existing one. Which one overlaps the other depends on the order of the nodes.